# Locking a single bool variable when multithreading?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

Recently I have seen this code in a WebSite, and my question is the following:

```
        private bool mbTestFinished = false;

        private bool IsFinished()
        {
            lock( mLock )
            {
                return mbTestFinished;
            }
        }

        internal void SetFinished()
        {
            lock( mLock )
            {
                mbTestFinished = true;
            }
        }
```

In a multithread environment, is really necessary to lock the access to the `mbTestFinished`?

Comment: It is the most provable mechanism for ensuring it isn't a CPU-cached read (which would not work well between threads) - `volatile` would work too, but for reasons that are too complex (this isn't the *intent* of `volatile`, but rather: a side-effect)

Comment: @MarcGravell I’ve always thought that _was_ the intent of `volatile`; any chance you might drop a good link that explains what is?

Comment: @romkyns: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4103879/158779) provides some insight.

Comment: @BrianGideon Thanks! Having read that, it seems that either it _is_ the intended use, or `lock` also only accidentally achieves the desired effect, wouldn’t you agree?

Comment: @romkyns: Well sort of. Except that `lock` actually *does* guarantee a fresh read because the memory barrier appears *before* the actual read. `volatile` puts the memory barrier *after* the read. I discuss this tangentially when explaining how `Thread.VolatileRead` is implemented at the bottom of my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8417285/158779).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is needed. .Net environment uses some optimizations, and sometimes if a memory location is accessed frequently, data is moved into CPU registers. So, in this case, if mbTestFinished is in a CPU register, then a thread reading it may get a wrong value. Thus using the volatile key ensures, all accesses to this variable is done at the memory location, not at the registers.
On the otherhand, I have no idea of the frequency of this occurence. This may occur at a very low frequency.

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion, no, the lock is superfluous here, for two reasons:

1. Boolean variables cannot cause assignment tearing like `long` for example, hence locking is not necessary.
2. To solve the visibility problem `volatile` is enough. It's true that the `lock` introduces an implicit fence, but since the `lock` is not required for atomicity, `volatile` is enough.

Comment: This is true assuming the code shown is the *only* thing using the lock. If there are other places where `mLock` is taken, the conversion to `volatile` could break things.

Comment: @romkyns: Yes, I'm assuming it's a self-contained scenario.

Answer (score 7):

If mLock is **ONLY** for the variable **mbTestFinished**, then it's a bit of an overkill. Instead, you can use **volatile** or **Interlocked**, because both are *User-Mode constructs* for thread synchronization. **lock** (or **Monitor**) is a *Hybrid Construct*, in the sense that it is well optimized to avoid transiting from/to the *Kernel-Mode* whenever possible. The book "CLR via C#" has a in-depth discussion of these concepts.