# What is actually guaranteed for a volatile field in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile

I am confused with the documentation for .NET/C# regarding the `volatile` keyword vs `System.Threading.Thread.VolatileRead`/`VolatileWrite` and `System.Threading.Volatile.Read/Write`. I am trying to understand what exactly is guaranteed for a volatile field and what exactly these methods are doing.

I thought `volatile` provides the release/acquire semantics, but the documentation for `Thread.VolatileRead`/`VolatileWrite` makes me wonder if my understanding is actually correct.

This is the language reference for volatile: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile

> Adding the volatile modifier ensures that all threads will observe
>   volatile writes performed by any other thread in the order in which
>   they were performed. There is no guarantee of a single total ordering
>   of volatile writes as seen from all threads of execution.

So far makes sense. This is the language specification: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#volatile-fields

> For volatile fields, such reordering optimizations are restricted:
>
> A read of a volatile field is called a volatile read. A volatile read has "acquire semantics"; that is, it is guaranteed to occur prior
>   to any references to memory that occur after it in the instruction
>   sequence.
>       A write of a volatile field is called a volatile write. A volatile write has "release semantics"; that is, it is guaranteed to happen
>   after any memory references prior to the write instruction in the
>   instruction sequence.
>
> These restrictions ensure that all threads will observe volatile
>   writes performed by any other thread in the order in which they were
>   performed. A conforming implementation is not required to provide a
>   single total ordering of volatile writes as seen from all threads of
>   execution.

Again, this looks like `volatile` provides the release/acquire semantics.

But then I look at the documentation for Thread.VolatileRead:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.volatileread?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Thread_VolatileRead_System_Int64__

> Reads the value of a field. The value is the latest written by any
>   processor in a computer, regardless of the number of processors or the
>   state of processor cache. ... On a multiprocessor system, VolatileRead
>   obtains the very latest value written to a memory location by any
>   processor. This might require flushing processor caches.

For Thread.VolatileWrite:

> Writes a value to a field immediately, so that the value is visible to
>   all processors in the computer.

This looks stricter then an individual store/load fence (release/acquire), specifically the part about flushing processor caches, i.e. more strict guarantee than just `volatile`. But then the same document says:

> In C#, using the volatile modifier on a field guarantees that all
>   access to that field uses VolatileRead or VolatileWrite

So my question is - what is guaranteed for a `volatile` field with respect to the store buffer - just release/acquire, or the stronger Thread.VolatileRead/Write guarantees? Or is my understanding about `VolatileRead/Write` wrong and these are the same as `volatile`?

Comment: [Threading in C# - Memory Barriers and Volatility](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Memory_Barriers_and_Volatility) -- [A reproducible example of volatile usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6164770/7444103) -- [What is the purpose of 'volatile' keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4103879/7444103)

Comment: Being confused with the `volatile` keyword is absolutely normal. I have tried to understand this keyword for months, and I am still at a loss. My takeaway from repeatedly failing to completely understand this keyword is that I should avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no difference between `System.Threading.Thread.VolatileRead/VolatileWrite` and `System.Threading.Volatile.Read/Write` - these are identical helper methods that mimic a full memory barrier before read or write (not necessary the `MFENCE` instruction). Here is the internal implementation:

```cs
public static void VolatileWrite(ref sbyte address, sbyte value)
{
  Thread.MemoryBarrier();
  address = value;
}
```

2. A `volatile` variable uses(-ed) acquire/release semantics on the obsolete IA processor architecture (Itanium) with a weaker memory model.
3. With the most popular x86 architecture, the `volatile` modifier avoids compiler optimizations and also may use instructions with `lock` prefix to guarantee consistency.

All in all, the compiler may use various tricks to comply with the [C# memory model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pedram/clr-2-0-memory-model), which states:

> 3. No reads or writes can move before a **volatile** read or after a **volatile** write
> 4. All writes have the effect of **volatile** write

Comment: `mfence` isn't used for `volatile` variables actually, nor any other fence, just normal loads and stores ([example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANALiAhgZwLYB8ACAmAjAWAChMBmAAhzIGEyBvIsxsgNwHsAbROAS3YFMy3AHZwyYANwMmpQSLIBZABQBKOlKZMA9JrIB3AE7c4fEGSGsyqAGZ8hAYz7qNYsgF4yUbJMLOtO/XyIACam5pY29o4+vhQA7GLeGgC+RElAA==))

Comment: you are right, did some research and confirm the statement